# requestAnimationFrame doublebuffering?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I'm incredibly curious about these things and unfortunately Google isn't helping. Apparently, `window.requestAnimationFrame(callback)` in JavaScript basically just fires the given callback function "when the browser is ready". But...

If I had a massive list of direct CSS style manipulation within a single callback, would the browser update the HTML/CSS contents on the screen **after** the callback has concluded, or **during**? Is there even a way to find out? Considering it sounds dependent on the browser's implementation.

I imagine that if the browser updates during the callback, then since the list is so massive, a user with an extremely slow computer will notice the gradual updating of elements on the screen. Whereas if the contents are updated after the callback has fired, then couldn't the browser utilize low-level, "whole-screen" double-buffering functions to blit the updates seemingly at once?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, it would be *after*; there is usually no change in visual state between the beginning of a JavaScript event/stack execution, and its end. The state effects are applied afterward. (There may be some exception if you are running a debugger and stepping through line by line)

Comment: Would you also happen to know whether multiple `requestAnimationFrame` callbacks made near-simultaneously  are executed one after the other? If this were the case, I would think that it's more efficient to place the recursive `requestAnimationFrame` calls at the beginning of the callback. Just in case the callback takes forever to complete and so it doesn't end up stuttering. Does this sound correct, or?

Comment: The risk of stuttering will become real anytime that "*the callback takes forever to complete*". JavaScript always has to execute on the UI thread. It doesn't seem like it, because any calls that might take more than a nanosecond are usually implemented asynchronously, with a callback function. For instance, setting style properties on its own doesn't take a lot of time - it's when the browser has to apply those effects that takes a bit more processing power.